# Symfony 4 Bundle Development

Tags: configuration, bundles, symfony4

I am trying to write a bundle to manage common functions across multiple App development in Symfony 4.

I have created a new blank App and new Blank bundles to which I have gradually been adding functionality.  To get both annotation routing and twig template paths I have had to add details to of the paths to the App config to get the bundle to work.  This seems strange to me as I had hoped that the bundle configuration would be self contained, placing appropriate hooks for the App to grab and use.

I have added a route file in the App at config/route/hillrange_admin.yaml

```
hillrange_admin:
    resource: '@HillrangeAdminBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
    prefix: /hillrange/admin/
```

The other file I have alters in the App is for the twig template paths, in config/packages/twig.yaml

```
twig:
    default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/templates'
    paths:
        '%kernel.project_dir%/templates/bundles/HillrangeAdmin': hillrange_admin
        '%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/hillrange/admin/Resources/views': hillrange_admin
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
```

This was the only way I could get the overrode of templates as discussed at https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/overriding.html.  This article does not mention any settings required to make the system work correctly.

So my question:  What am I missing that I need to add configuration to the App to make the bundle work.  I have read a lot of documentation, but as yet I have not found the information that makes it all work as I expect to work?

The bundle structure follows https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html and the App follows the structure mentioned at https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/creating-the-project.html

Thanks for any thoughts.

Craig